# Change row drag animation

Tags: qt, drag

I create a QTableWidget subclass who can recive drop both from external file and his internal rows. While dragging a row to move it in a different position, a copy of the row appear anchored to the mouse cursor. There's a way to remove the anchored row copy while dragging?

Here is the class:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QDrag>
#include "dtablewidget.h"
#include "nofocusproxystyle.cpp"

DTableWidget::DTableWidget(QWidget *parent) : QTableWidget(parent) {
    //set widget default properties:
    setFrameStyle(QFrame::Sunken | QFrame::StyledPanel);
    viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true); //set accept drop on viewport
    setDragDropOverwriteMode(false); //set drag drop overwrite to false
    setDropIndicatorShown(true); //show drop indicator on tag drop
    setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove); //enable internal drag drop on tablular dispaly
    setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows); //enable selection of entire row
    setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);//preventing editing
    setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    setShowGrid(false);
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    setWordWrap(false);
    setStyleSheet("selection-background-color: yellow;"
                  "selection-color: #002041;"
                  "font-size: 75%;"
                  );
    setStyle(new NoFocusProxyStyle(style()));
}

void DTableWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) {
    event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void DTableWidget::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event) {
    event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void DTableWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) {
    event->acceptProposedAction();
    if (event->mimeData()->urls().size() > 0) {

        emit dropped(event->mimeData());
    }
    else {
        QPoint old_coordinates = QPoint(-1,-1);
        if(currentItem() != NULL) //Check if user is not accessing empty cell
        {
            old_coordinates = QPoint(currentItem()->row(), currentItem()->column());
        }
        QTableWidget::dropEvent(event);
        if(this->itemAt(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y()) != NULL && old_coordinates != QPoint(-1, -1))
        {
            emit moved(old_coordinates.x(), itemAt( event->pos().x(), event->pos().y())->row());
        }
    }
}

void DTableWidget::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event) {
    event->accept();
}

void DTableWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    emit keyboard(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `QAbstractItemView::startDrag()` and don't set an image in QMimeData. You can base your implementation by looking at https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#_ZN17QAbstractItemView9startDragE6QFlagsIN2Qt10DropActionEE